# How does JS engine manipulates undeclared variable?

Tags: javascript, variables

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta lan="en-us" charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>

    <p>Counting with a local variable.</p>

    <p id="demo"></p>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction('+')">Count +</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction('-')">Count -</button>

    <script>
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 0;
      function add(number){
        var counter = 0;
        return function() {return counter += number;} 
      }
      function sub(number){
        var counter = 0;
        return function() {return counter -= number;} 
      }

      var counterIncr = add(1);
      var counterDicr = sub(1);

      function myFunction(s){
        if( s == "+"){
          /*this.*/counter1 = counterIncr();
        }
        else if (s == "-"){
          /*this.*/counter2 = counterDicr();
        }

        if(!counter2 && counter1){
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = counter1;
        }
        else if(!counter1 && counter2){
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = counter2;
        }
        else if(counter1 && counter2){
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (counter1 + counter2);
        }
      }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

During my study on JS closures I've extended a W3C example, implementing an HTML page with two buttons. The example has just one button. The first button increases a counter on-click and the second button decreases that counter. A function "myFunction" is defined that uses two variables "counter1" and counter2" in order to do the job. These variables were declared as this.counter1 and this.counter2 and this page's implementation works as it's expected.
My question:
When I omit "this" from counter1 and counter2 declaration (...just for fun)  my page still works (surely not in strict mode) but only when both buttons have been clicked once. How this behavior could be explained or how does JS engine manipulates (treats) undeclared variables under the hood?

Answer (score 1):

A variable that is not explicitly declared, will always be a global variable automatically:

```js
function myFunction() {
  // explicitly declared variable (local)
  var explitic = "foo";
  
  // implicitly declared variable (global)
  implicit = "bar";
}
    
myFunction(); // call function

console.log(typeof explicit); // prints "undefined" since local
console.log(typeof implicit); // prints "string" since global
```

More examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#Implicit_globals_and_outer_function_scope).

Strict mode, on the other hand, doesn't accept implicitly declared variables at all:

```js
"use strict";

var explicitGlobal = "foo";

function myFunction() {
  // works because explicitGlobal is already defined
  explicitGlobal = "foo2";

  // Uncaught ReferenceError: implicit is not defined
  implicit = "bar";
}
        
myFunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables that are "undeclared" are implicitly assigned as global variables (and properties of the global object) in non-strict ("sloppy") mode. You are in sloppy mode, so that's why your code works.

```js
;(function sloppy () {
  sloppyVar = 'sloppy'
})()

console.log(sloppyVar) //=> 'sloppy'

;(function strict () {
  "use strict";
  strictVar = 'strict' //=> throws ReferenceError
})()
```

You probably shouldn't be using `this` to refer to the global object anyways, because that is deprecated as of strict mode.

```js
;(function sloppy () {
  console.log(this === window) //=> true
})()

;(function strict () {
  "use strict";
  console.log(this) //=> undefined
})()
```

It is more correct to use the `window` reference when you're working in the browser, so instead you would write:

```
window.globalVar = 'stuff'
```

Comment: Could the sloppy mode somehow explain why the page displays the correct (based on clicks) value of the counter after both buttons have been clicked once? Why the page behaves like it doesn't "feel" first clicks?